# Change a web programmed in ASP.net to WordPress from scratch in the same Hosting

Tags: migration, installation, hosting

I have a website developed in ASP.net. I want to change all that website to WordPress, that is, make a website from scratch in the same hosting and then delete the website developed in ASP.net. I need to know the correct solution on how to work with wordpress on the same server without affecting the old web to be able to work online with the new web in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are a bit off-topic, but typically you would set up the new WordPress site locally or as a staging site, meaning it could be on the final server, but you're using a different URL while you get everything set up. Once you have all the content loaded, all the themes and plugins how you want them, you then run a database migration - there are various plugins and scripts to do so. Finally, after making sure you have a clean backup of the old site, you can remove those files, and the WordPress site takes over.

Comment: What I plan to do is to create a subdomain on the hosting and install wordpress on the subdomain, once I have finished the website make a clone of the new website, proceed to delete the old one and upload the new website to the server. The problem already worries me about how to delete the old web developed with ASP.net.